# GUI adress and Integrated adress are 79 Characters

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

My Exchange asks for 64 character address that I can send to my GUI. A newly generated Payment ID is 16 characters. How can I get 64 character address to withdraw from my Exchange?

Answer (score 2):

A regular Monero address is 95 characters long.
An integrated address is 106 characters long.

As far as I know there is no Monero address format having 79 characters.

When withdrawing from an exchange to your own wallet, you don't even need to use a payment ID. But if you want to use one, or if your exchange requires one, you can use any hexadecimal string you want (either 16 hexadecimal characters for a short payment ID, or 64 hexadecimal characters for a long payment id).